# Ordenação Array de Objetos javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, testes-de-unidade

Estou escrevendo uma biblioteca que implementa diversos algoritmos de ordenação tudo ia bem ate eu executar a ordenação de um array de objetos.

```
const exec = (array, fnCompare) =>{
    return sort.bubble(array, fnCompare);
  }

  describe('Array Obejetos', ()=> {
    let array_in = [
      {name: "Alex", age: 12},
      {name: "Max", age: 34},
      {name: "Mary", age: 9},
      {name: "Justin", age: 53}
    ];

    let array_out_asc = [
      {name: "Mary", age: 9},
      {name: "Alex", age: 12},
      {name: "Max", age: 34},
      {name: "Justin", age: 53}
    ]

    const fnASC = (a,b) => {
      return a.age < b.age; //linha onde o console reclama que o erro ocorreu
    };

    it('Ordenação crescente', ()=> {
      assert.deepEqual(array_out_asc, exec(array_in, fnASC));
    });
  });
```

Mas acabo tendo a seguinte saida no meu teste de unidade:

```
 24 passing (29ms)
  1 failing

  1) Bubble Array Objetos Ordenação crescente:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined
      at fnASC (test/bubblesort.spec.js:85:23)
      at core/bubble.js:25:10
      at Array.forEach (native)
      at Object.array.forEach [as bubble] (core/bubble.js:24:11)
      at exec (test/bubblesort.spec.js:10:17)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/bubblesort.spec.js:89:39)
```

O erro diz que não foi possivel ler a propiedade age, no entanto se eu adicionar um console log dentro da função fnASC descrita acima ela imprime o objeto perfeitamente. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar havendo ?

Comment: O que está acontecendo é que em determinado momento da execução tenta-se fazer a leitura da propriedade age de um objeto **undefined**, ou seja, uma posição vazia do vetor/JSON. Tente verificar a condição de parada da sua função de ordenação, para garantir que nunca caia em um posição inválida.

Comment: O que tem o ficheiro `test/bubblesort.spec.js`?

Comment: Existe uma quantidade significativa de código para colocar aqui vou deixar o link do github https://github.com/1fabiopereira/node-sort-library caso queira dar uma olhada, e vou verifica o que me disse.

Comment: Você estava @Sergio correto minha condição de  parada executava uma vez a mais, muito obrigado.